# My app IOS can't connect to web service "CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed"

Tags: ios, ionic3

Has anyone with the iOS 9 beta 1 had this issue?
I added the IOS `sudo ionic cordova platform add ios` The IOS Folder is added and the `application.xcodeproj` is added

My app was running successfully however, all AJAX failed.

Answer (score 0):

Add this snippets to your .plist file.

```html
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow insecure HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

and

```xml
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <!--Connect to anything (this is probably BAD)-->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: I Tried That, and it Didn't Work

Comment: Did you add <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string> ?

Comment: yes i already add it :(